# preference screen within layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been going crazy for the last couple of hours. Can't get this working:
I've got a preference, a layout and activity. but i can't get the preference within the layout...
preference:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference 
       android:key="show_numbers"
       android:title="show tile numbers"
       android:summary="display the correct location of the tiles"
       android:defaultValue="false"   />
   <ListPreference
       android:key="grid_size"
       android:title="Grid Size"
       android:summary="puzzle size" 
       android:entries="@array/gridSizeTitles"
       android:entryValues="@array/gridSizeValues"
       android:defaultValue="3"  />
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

layout:

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbgcolor" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:text="Sliding Puzzle"
            android:textColor="#242FF0"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivHeader"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtvHeader"
            android:contentDescription="Sliding Puzzle Icon"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/slidingpuzzleicon" />
    </RelativeLayout>


 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutHeader"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- THIS IS THE PLACE I WANT TO GET THE PREFERENCE.
     I ALSO WANT BE ABLE TO POSITION THE PREFERENCE VIEWS. -->

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

any help would be welcome.

thanks in advance, olijf

Comment: i don't think you can do that. may be with a preference screen you can fetch the top view and inject your layout there, but i'm not even sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- THIS IS THE PLACE I WANT TO GET THE PREFERENCE.
     I ALSO WANT BE ABLE TO POSITION THE PREFERENCE VIEWS. -->
```

Then you will need to draw your own UI for that, rather than using a `PreferenceScreen`.

The point behind the `PreferenceScreen` system is to provide a standardized way of collecting preferences, so that users know what to expect and how the UI works. What you want is to implement a non-standardized ways of collecting preferences. You are welcome to do so, but you will need to roll your own UI for that.